# Gradle settings error in Android Studio

Tags: linux, gradle, android-studio

I recently downloaded gradle-1.6 directly in Linux Mint 14, and copied it to the directory /usr/bin/android-studio/plugins. Then I copied the gradle.jar file to /usr/bin/android-studio/lib directory.

Result:
org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings

I need help with this. No other post gives suggestions for Linux, just Windows.